# Briefly hibernate PC during Dropbox Sync

Tags: windows-7, sync, dropbox, hibernate

I'm in the middle of moving a large number of files to Dropbox from my PC laptop (running Windows 7). I'm wondering if it's safe to temporarily put my PC to hibernate while I go home, and then set it up again when I get there? I accidentally set it up to move rather than copy the files, so I'm a bit worried things may get lost while the laptop is in hibernate mode. Any advice?

Comment: Dropbox picks up from where it left off, so I don't see why not...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is not a problem. If you stop Dropbox for any reason while synchronizing a file, it will continue once it's started again.

If you overwrite any file, it will result in two files, one of them having "User's conflicted copy" added to the file name.

You may find it useful to run a command like this on the Windows computer you are leaving:

```
shutdown /h /t 3600
```

This will hibernate your computer after one hour (3600 seconds).